# why i have this Exception in java : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, nullpointerexception

This is my main codes:

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

Student[] starray=new Student[5];

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    System.out.println("enter:");
    starray[i].name=input.next();   
    System.out.println("enter:");
    starray[i].family=input.next(); 
    System.out.println("enter:");
    starray[i].sid=input.nextInt();
}      
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        System.out.println(starray[i].name);
```

and i have one class :

```
String name,family;
Integer sid;

Student(){
       name="kh";
       family="kh";
       sid=0;}
```

when i run it have Exception below:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at testcodes.TestCodes.main(TestCodes.java:19)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: You are not creating any students in the array.... All i see is you are making the array but not creating a `new Student()`   @Chrismas007 I think his question is in the title....

Comment: @3kings Saw this in Triage so I wasn't able to do an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java in this case is very similar to C++. In C++ when you declare an array of objects, all them still have not been initialized (these is no real objects within it), in other words the array is only a *place holder* for objects.

So your statement

```
Student[] starray = new Student[5];
```

in the form of visually could be

```
starray --> +------+------+------+------+------+
            | null | null | null | null | null |
            +------+------+------+------+------+
```

And after this statement

```
starray[0] = new Student();
```

would be

```
starray --> +------+------+------+------+------+
            |      | null | null | null | null |
            +---|--+------+------+------+------+
                |
                v
            +------------------+
            | Student Instance |
            +------------------+
```

Answer (score 5):

`Student[] starray = new Student[5];` creates just the *container*. Every element within that container will be `null`.

You need to create each one in turn. Within your loop, consider

`starray[i] = new Student();`

Better still, build a strongly typed constructor to a `Student`, taking the name etc. as parameters. This will help to increase program stability.